# Is there a software to create iPhone icons for any size?

Tags: images, iphone, icons

I use http://www.quirco.com/iPhoneIcon/ to make icons for iPhone. Unfortunately, it doesn't allow the dimension go over 114 x 114. I want a higher dimension because I display the larger icon in the app. My question is, what's the best way to convert a image to an icon for iPhone for arbitrary size? I'm happy for a paid solution.

Comment: Will Xcode let you use a larger icon? Why not just use a separate image in your app?

Comment: I want to display the same icon in the app as a separate image, but with a larger size. I can't simply show the image because the image needs to have the four corners shaped.

Comment: Ah, okay, I understand now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You need Photoshop, tho.
http://www.pixelresort.com/blog/app-icon-template/

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative: Try as [IconFly](http://iconfly.aperio-lux.com)
There you can create icons for Mac (ICNS, iconset), iPad and iPhone.